# C# comments tutorial

Tags: c#, comments

I would like to know which one is the best material that I can hand out to my students about "*C# comments*".

Comment: Without a doubt it must be [Strunk and White](http://www.bartleby.com/141/).

Comment: Take a look at this question I asked on SO about code documentation. There's some interesting insight in there that you may wish to repackage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288298/code-documentation-how-much-is-too-much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite interesting to do with the xml comments: http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html

These get read by [sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/) too... :o)

Answer (score 13):

Something that I read a while ago (and have lost track of where) is:

- Beginners comment nothing
- Apprentices comment the obvious
- Journeymen comment the reason for doing it
- Masters comment the reason for not doing it another way

Comment: Perfect.  Printing, and putting on my cube wall

Comment: I will most certainly put that on my wall, but I think our professor was hoping for something that took a little longer to read. :-)

Answer (score 12):

[This Post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000749.html) by Jeff Atwood on his blog [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com) goes into the purpose of comments in general.  Something you might think is 'duh' really isn't -- especially in the 'real world' when you see comments like the one below:

```
//Connect to the Database
Db.Connect();
```

And of course, there's the corollary to that post: [Coding Without Comments](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001150.html).

Answer (score 2):

### Inside VS

Comments are relatively simple.

You can use for **single line** :

```
//This is a single line comment
```

You can use for **multiple line**:

```
/*
Multiple lines
*/
```

For **method** you can use  :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a description
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Description of variable SENDER</param>
    /// <param name="e">Description of variable E</param>
```

### Outside VS

When you go in the **Project Property** you can output all comments into XML and manipulate them.

### Good practice

Comments should not be used to describe WHAT the code do but WHY or HOW if it's not clear.